# Errno 2 No such file or directory: 'Dataset'

Tags: python, path

I'm trying to run a code on colab, but getting

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Dataset'
```

error every time. I tried creating a subfolder named 1 and stored all the files in the subfolder, but still no luck.

My code:

```
path = '/content/DIV2K_train_HR/'
DatasetSubclass = dset.ImageFolder(root = path)

class Dataset(DatasetSubclass):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    hr_size = kwargs.pop('hr_size', [96,96])
    lr_size = kwargs.pop('lr_size', [24,24])
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Post your whole code and the whole error message with full traceback. The code you posted is not even runnable.

Comment: Is `path` supposed to be relative?  Did you mean 'content/DIV2K_train_HR/'?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning`, `deep-learning`, or `pytorch` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

1. you have assigned the path of **folder** not the path of **file**
   which you want to use.
2. you can directly copy the file path and assign it to the root variable like
   given in the below image

[review img below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIhy8.png)

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with pytorch, but I would expect the `root` parameter of a class called `ImageFolder` to be a folder and not a particular file.